# ¿Cómo subir videos usando Django?

Tags: django

Quisiera saber cómo puedo  guardar un video en una base de datos para después usarlo. Intenté hacer un modelo asi:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='videos')
```

Pero a la hora de guardarlo me da error:

```
TypeError at /admin/lab_virtual/video/add/ 
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/lab_virtual/video/add/
Django Version:     1.10.5
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Exception Location:     C:\Python36-32\lib\ntpath.py in abspath, line 542
Python Executable:  C:\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version:     3.6.0
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\Pilin\\PycharmProjects\\Tesis',
 'C:\\Users\\Pilin\\PycharmProjects\\Tesis',
 'C:\\Python36-32\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python36-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Python36-32',
 'C:\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.10.5-py3.6.egg']

Server time:    Tue, 11 Jul 2017 13:41:34 -0500
```

¿No existe alguna biblioteca como PIL que sirva para vídeos?

Comment: Hola Pedro, la pregunta es: ¿cómo los estás guardando?

Comment: muestra parte del codigo `HTML` que estas usando para subir el video, y si puedes poner parte de la vista y tu configuración url sería mucho mejor

Comment: Guardar video en una base de datos es una mala idea, por qué no mejor los guardas en un folder y en la BD guardas la ruta de donde se encuentra?

Comment: En realidad no los estás subiendo a ninguna base de datos, pero falta ver como estás procesando la vista y como creaste tu plantilla. Sin esos datos es complicado ayudarte.

Comment: Ya resolvi el error era problema en el setting.py , gracias

Comment: Como lo resolviste??